# ros::Time.now().toSec() optimized out

Tags: ros, optimization, cmake, rostime

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

Using ROS Hydro on Ubuntu 12.04. I am trying to see the result of ros::Time.now().toSec() while debugging a node, but the debugger says the value is optimized out.

I know that normally we can change a CMake file to change the debug type of a binary, however, since this is part of ROS deb package, I am not sure how to go about it.

Any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196171/ros::time.now().tosec()-optimized-out/) by [Juan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4088/juan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 208 on 2014-10-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assume you have something like:

```
double seconds = ros::Time.now().toSec();
```

Now you try to debug the value seconds? (Other: you can't debug into the functions now() or toSec() because the deb is - obviously correctly - build as release...; If you want to debug this you have to recompile it yourself from source in debug mode...)

Assuming you can't access the seconds value, it is because it is optimized out in your code (or your code is not even build with debug info). You can change this by setting the build type for catkin via command like like:

with debug info, with optimization:

```
catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo
```

with debug info, without optimization:

```
catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
```

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2